Nintendo Wii zoom in animation transition with HTML, CSS and Javascript
I would like to make an animation like the Wii menu transition when you click a channel:
Wii Menu Video (min 0:16)
As you can see, window zooms in to the channel and then the channel page opens. Nothing around the channel distorts, meaning that the channel component isn't growing in size (I suppose).
It is said that Wii menu is coded on HTML, so it should be possible right?
I tried making the image where you click bigger as the background gets smaller, but the result is far from the original. Also, I couldn't find a framework or library capable of doing this, not even a website with an animation like this. If you find something, let me know.

I built using some AI assistance. Idea is creating a fixed position node on same position as the cell that was clicked in the grid. Using getBoundingClientRect helps a lot. And of course using transition to change the coordinates, i.e zoom.


const gridContainer = document.getElementById("gridContainer")
const closeButton = document.getElementById("closeButton")
const gridColumns = 9
const gridRows = 3

var clonedCell
var rect

function createGrid() {
  for (let i = 0; i < gridColumns * gridRows; i++) {
    const cell = document.createElement("div")
    cell.className = "grid-cell"
    cell.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=${i})`
    cell.addEventListener("click", () => zoomCell(cell))
    gridContainer.appendChild(cell)
  }
}

function zoomCell(cell) {
  rect = cell.getBoundingClientRect()
  const startTop = rect.top
  const startLeft = rect.left
  const startWidth = rect.width
  const startHeight = rect.height

  clonedCell = cell.cloneNode(true)
  document.body.appendChild(clonedCell)
  clonedCell.style.position = "fixed"
  clonedCell.style.top = startTop + "px"
  clonedCell.style.left = startLeft + "px"
  clonedCell.style.width = startWidth + "px"
  clonedCell.style.height = startHeight + "px"
  clonedCell.style.zIndex = "10"
  clonedCell.style.borderRadius = "20px"

  requestAnimationFrame(function() {

    gridContainer.style.opacity = 0;

    clonedCell.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease"
    clonedCell.style.top = "0"
    clonedCell.style.left = "0"
    clonedCell.style.width = "100vw"
    clonedCell.style.height = "100vh"
    clonedCell.addEventListener("click", resetZoom)
  })
}

function resetZoom() {
  if (clonedCell) {
    clonedCell.style.top = rect.top + "px"
    clonedCell.style.left = rect.left + "px"
    clonedCell.style.width = rect.width + "px"
    clonedCell.style.height = rect.height + "px"
    gridContainer.style.opacity = 1;


    setTimeout(() => {
      clonedCell.remove()
      clonedCell = null;

    }, 500)
  }
}

createGrid()
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 250px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.grid-cell {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
<div class="grid-container" id="gridContainer"></div>




I think this is really close, but if you see the original animation, the images (channels) around the one clicked also get closer to the screen
